# What's the current way to bump both versions using fastlane in Xcode projects?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fastlane

In "modern" Xcode projects there is no full-blown `.plist` anymore. The old way to bump both versions (Marketing version and bundle version) do not longer work using trusted lane [`increment_version_number`](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/increment_version_number/).

I found "newer" lanes like [`increment_version_number_in_xcodeproj`](https://github.com/SiarheiFedartsou/fastlane-plugin-versioning) but these compiles the project many times which is not what I can do on a large scaled app.

What's the current best practice to bump both versions without having a plist file? I checked other fastlane plugins and shell scripts but these do not work, too.

**Other posts:**
[Xcode 14 and missing sync with CFBundleVersion edit in Info.plist during Build/Archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73906151/xcode-14-and-missing-sync-with-cfbundleversion-edit-in-info-plist-during-build-a)